# Applications of this factorization method?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

### Background

So I was watching this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?si=n0yj5TG7lfKWovdY&fbclid=IwAR3OE4FrGv5ii5XMuMNPtGSVX0QVUd27mPEaRlK9ptV5pHx5dhxFZ0DzEbU&v=wJcLAkjLpKs&feature=youtu.be). It poses a problem solve:
$$ 2^x = x^4$$

### My Method

$$2^x = x^2 x^2$$

Or:

$$ 2^{x/2} 2^{x/2} = x^2 x^2$$

By prime factorization theorem and symmetry:

$$x/2 = 2$$

### Extending this method to other problems

We only restrict ourselves to integer solutions:

$$a^b c^d = x^4 y^6$$

where $d > b$, then:

$$ a^b c^d = (xy)^4 y^2$$

Or:

$$ a^{b-2} c^{d-2} (ac)^2 = (xy)^4 y^2$$

Using prime factorization theorem it should be possible to rearrange the primes such that one solution amongst the set of solutions:

$$ac = y^2$$
$$a^{b-2} c^{d-2} = (xy)^4$$

Simplyfying:

$$ac = y^2 \implies y = a^{1/2}c^{1/2} $$
$$a^{b-2} c^{d-2} = (xy)^4 \implies x = a^{b/4-1} c^{d/4-1} $$

### Question

What are these set of problems in number theory known as? Are there any interesting applications where they show up?

Comment: Problems in which only integer solutions are of interest are often called [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation), after the Greek mathematician Diophantus of Alexandria.  The term *exponential Diophantine equation* is appropriate when (as here) unknowns are allowed to appear as exponents.   It asks a lot of your Readers to anticipate what "these set of problems in number theory" consist of more precisely.